# How to Query with Redux Store and GraphQl in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

i've an issue with my GraphQl Query and Mutation call. I built an component for the app like this

```
class ABC extends Component {
   componentDidMount(){
      this.props.eventuser({
        variables: {
            eventName: {id:this.props.activeEvent.cell.id}

        },

    }).then(response => {
        //response ...
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log('Error',err);
    });
   }
   render(){
     some render things
   }
}
function mapStateToProps(store) {
   return {
        activeEvent: store.activeEvent
   };
}
const Save= connect(mapStateToProps)(ABC);
export default compose(
graphql(Query1,
   name:"eventuser"
   }),
graphql(Query2,{
   name:"alluser"
   }),
graphql(Mutation1,{
   name:"updateEventdata"
   }))(Save);
```

the Queries need the ID which comes with activeEvent.
My Problem now is, that GraphQl is there before the activeEvent id is there (I think so).

I had to rebuilt this part of the app for refetching, and the normal withApollo() function of react-apollo does not have something like that (or I didnt found it).
So the code look's a little bit messed, because its an snippling of old and "new" code.

If there is a possibility to refetch with withApollo() I would like to go on with this. Otherwise I need help to inject the ID of the activeEvent as and Prop/State/Variable for the Query

additional informations:

- there is an redux store which holds the ID's and some other stuff
- its an component of the app, not the full app

Comment: In your reducer try adding initial state for `{ activeEvent: { cell: { id: '"" } } }`. This should stop it from throwing an when the component is first rendered.

Comment: there is already an initial state, the problem is not that its not found or something, problem is that the query has no id, but its already dispatched.

  the dispatch is before the component changes, so normaly it is already there, but die graphql function has no access to the properties (i think).

the "connect()" is after the call of grapql()

    const Save= connect(mapStateToProps)(ABC);
    export default compose( "graphql bla")(Save);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a kind of a solution for the problem. You need to pass through the ID as a prop via the parent element. Looks like this:
**`App.js`**
`//call of the Event, passes the eventID from the Redux to the child element
    <Eventoverview eventName={this.props.activeEvent.cell.id} />`

Then in the child element the graphql export looks like this:
 **`Eventoverview.js`**

`export default compose(`
    `connect(mapStateToProps)` 
`,graphql(Query1,{`
   `options: (props)=>({ variables: {
            eventName: {id:props.eventName}},}),
    name:"eventuser"`
`}),graphql(Query2,{
    name:"alluser"`
`}),graphql(Mutation1,{
    name:"updateEventdata"`
`}))(Eventoverview);`

now the ID is used in the Query and i get my answers